# it is possible make sql function from php/c file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my data base and one of the fields is encoded by a php function. now I need to make a function to decode that field in mysql side. something like this:

```
SELECT permissions,decodePermission(id,permissions) as decoded_permissions FROM table
```

I try to use `CREATE TABLE` in mysql but it is very weak and in sql i don't have functions like **explode()**, **base64_decode()** , **md5()** (that is exists in php). so now I wanna to know it is possible to make a function in mysql from a php,c or perl file? something like this: `LOAD FILE 'path/to/c/file'`

Comment: I know MySQL has `MD5`, and I've seen implementations of `explode` out there.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: md5 and explode is only for examples, big problem is there is no ARRAY data type in mysql

Comment: What exactly do you want the function (or procedure) to do?  You can't load arbitrary files in other languages and have MySQL run them.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function via php /c isnt possible.
What kind of encoding did you use? What functions?

Anyways, there are crypto functions in Mysql. have a look here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

It is also not pretty secure to get the decrypted data from mysql if you are not using ssl

Comment: the encryption method is unique for my project, and it is not an standard encryption method. it encrypt strings by using an key and row id

Comment: Then its better to get the encrypted data from mysql and decrypt them in your php script. Also as i said it isnt secure to get decrypted data if you dont use ssl

Comment: my problem is my table is users table and maybe have over 10000 rows there, if I select all of them a big data must transfer between php and mysql. I am trying to make a function in mysql side and ofter that destroy functions for security :P

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data from MySql encrypted, using your choice of language. Ideally, you want to fetch it over a secure connection (loopback, vpn or at least SSL).  Decrypt it as needed. Aim to use a standard encryption method.

Often times instead of encrypting/decrypting, a trap hash is used - results are encrypted and compared in an encrypted state. This is ideal for checking repeated phenomenon (i.e. Passwords).